# How to separate columns in R if you have one column with uneven rows?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, rows, frequency, dna-sequence

I have a .csv file where I have one column with 25-30 characters per row. I need to separate the one column into 25 columns each with its own character (or nucleotide) inside each. Thus, I will be ignoring the extra 0-5 nucleotides in each row.

The .csv files looks similar to this:

**Sequence**

- ATCGGTCGGGGGAT
- TGCTGGCAAA
- ACCGTCGAA
- ACTGGTAATTG

I need the table to look similar to this:

**Sequence**

- A T G C T
- G T A C T
- G G T C C
- A T G T G

If this information helps: the end goal for me is trying to find the nucleotide frequencys of each column that is why I need the columns to be separated.

I am very new to R so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `dput()` to provide data that we can cut/paste.

```
Sequence <- c("ATCGGTCGGGGGAT", "TGCTGGCAAA", "ACCGTCGAA", "ACTGGTAATTG")
```

The chop off the bits you don't need and split the rest:

```
Sequence <- substr(Sequence, 1, 5)
Sequence <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(Sequence, "")))
Sequence
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  A  T  C  G  G
# 2  T  G  C  T  G
# 3  A  C  C  G  T
# 4  A  C  T  G  G
```